# How can I add content at the end of a Microsoft Word docx document using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, ms-word, docx

I am using PowerShell to open and edit a docx file.
I was able to open an existing file and set the style, font and more...
My problem is with adding content. The content is added to the top of the file but I want to add it at the **end of the document**.
This is my working code:

```
$word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$word.Visible = $false
$out_path = ".\file.docx"
$doc = $word.documents.open($out_path)

$selections = $word.Selection
$selections.Font.Name = "Arial"
$selections.Font.Size = 16
$selections.paragraphFormat.Alignment = 2
$selections.TypeText("Hello World!`v")

$doc.Close()
$word.Quit()
```

This is the how I tested it:
I created a new docx file.
At the first run it will add the text to an empty existing word file.
If you run it again it will add the text but at the beginning of the document.
You can verify this by changing the String in the TypeText function before the second run.

I did not find any information about how to add a content at the end of the document using PowerShell.
I will appreciate any help,
Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried to go to last page?, (wdGoToPage,wdGoToAbsolute,pageNumber)

Comment: You will need to move the focus of the Word document in the ComObject. I believe that if you pipe your selections variable to `Get-Member` i.e. `$Selections | Get-Member` you will see a number of methods such as `InsertBefore`, `InsertAfter`, `StartOf` and `EndOf` amongst many others. The methods will give you some indication of what they require. The ComObject reference is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.selection.endof), but intended for VBA. There is [a module for PowerShell](https://github.com/EvotecIT/PSWriteWord) that does not rely on the ComObject